# replace a string if it Contains Format in c#

Tags: c#

I´m developing a Quality Management software to show Errors of a Provisioning tool.

therefore I read all errors from an XML and group them

but there are errors like: "Forcedtime 1.08.2016 17:51:00 is in the past"

Is It possible to find Date-Values like this in a string and delete them ?
I can't work with a hard coded replace cause there are many different values for the Date Time.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Try *regular expression* for this

Comment: It's called a pattern, not a format. Check regular expressions and pattern matching. In .NET regular expressions are provided by the Regex class. You can replace matches using the [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You'll find a brief intro in [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(\d{4}) (00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])
```

It checks for date time **1.08.2016 17:51:00**.
You have to compare this date format in your string if matches then replace it

Try to learn **reg exp**

Comment: You should remove `^` and `$` the match we are looking for is right in the middle of the string. You also forgot to escape the dots. Then you could write `\d{4}` to avoid the `\d` repetition

Answer (score 0):

Yet another suggestion is to read the XML as such and discard the nodes you don't like/need. Then process only the nodes left.

In fact, while the `Regex` will do the trick for replacing something in the text, it might not be a good fit since this is structured data as opposed to bunch of data in a string format.